# Differentiating between role based actions

Tags: usability, layout, visual-design, roles

**Context**

I have two types of users (Students and Administrator) who will be interacting with the preference view screen (Students select their desired preferences before while filling their admission forms).

Student can perform following actions after adding their preference:

1. Change Preference
2. Delete preference

Administrators can perform following actions on the preference added by student:

1. Edit preference details
2. Matriculate
3. Change Preference
4. Delete Preference

**Question**

How do I differentiate the views by keeping the overall visual design consistent?

I have two options

**First** one is to provide actions upfront in list view as follows
[image]
Screenshot attached above is a view for administrator. In case of students only delete and preference edit will be visible.

**Second** option is to add a menu in the list which will display all the actions. And the actions displayed in the menu will change upon roles.

[image]
But edit preference and matriculate hold a higher significance for administrator so menu will kind of make all the actions hold same importance.

Kindly suggest any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can split it, display the 2 more important actions (the ones the administrator will use the most) and hide the secondary options (the one he less likely will use) behind the menu.

You could also think about uniting "Edit preference details" and "Change preference", they sound like they could be put together, this way you could display three actions.